# mongoose insert data with promise

Tags: node.js, dictionary, mongoose, promise, bluebird

My goal is to insert a new country (with incremented country_id) into the db if it doesn't exist.  In that case I try to get the max country_id and insert a new country with country_id + 1.  Otherwise I don't do anything.

readFile is a promise to readfile, 
filetoArray changes that file content to an array, 
processMap processes each array element and decide if we store the info to mongodb or not

The problem is:

```
promise.promisifyAll(Country.findOne({}).sort({'zid' : -1}).exec()
```

always gives me the same result even when some data are already inserted into the database...

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CountrySchema = new Schema({
    zn: {type: String, required: true},
    zid: {type: Number, required: true}
});

var promise = require('bluebird');

function processMap(data){
    return promise.bind(data).then(insertCountry);
}

var insertCountry = function() {
    var googledata = this;  // from bind promise
    return promise.promisifyAll(Country.findOne({zn: googledata.country}).exec())
    .then(function(dbdata){ return {dbdata: dbdata, googledata: googledata}; })
    .then(insertCountryIfNotExist)
}

var insertCountryIfNotExist = function(data){
    return promise.promisifyAll(Country.findOne({}).sort({'zid' : -1}).exec())
    .then(function(d){
        var newc = new Country({zn: data.googledata.country, zid: d.zid + 1});
        return promise.promisifyAll(newc.saveAsync())
    });
}

// main code is here
readFile(file)
.then(filetoArray)
.map(processMap, {concurrency: 1})  // end of then
.then(function(data){
    console.log('done');
})
```

Comment: Promisify the model itself, as in `Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose.model('Country'))`, then use the added `Async` methods (like `findOneAsync`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Exec returns a [promise](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) inherited from [mpromise](https://github.com/aheckmann/mpromise), there's no need to use bluebird on your case or if you want to use bluebird, then don't mix the mongoose promises with blue bird.

some example:

```
var insertCountry = function() {
    var googledata = this;
    return Country.findOne({zn: googledata.country}).exec()
    .then(function(dbdata){ 
         return {dbdata: dbdata, googledata: googledata}; 
     })
    .then(function(data){
       return Country.findOne({}).sort({'zid' : -1}).exec()
          .then(function(d){
           var newc = new Country({zn: data.googledata.country, zid: d.zid + 1});
           return newc.save();
       })
    })
}
```

Comment: another question.  I declared a function like: getmaxcid = Country.findOne({}).sort({'zid' : -1}).exec(); and replaced the code above to return getmaxcid.then(d){xxxx}.  this doesn't work. Could you tell me what is happening here? (does that mean you cannot declare functions and reuse the code...?)

Comment: sorry my bad, you need to define a function every time you use data / params from a promise

Comment: I see. I declared a function and call it instead. It seems the function will create (and return) a new promise instead of giving me the same finished promises forever... thanks!